# (Matlab) SVM optimizer fails with large matrix

Tags: matlab, optimization, svm

I am trying to optimize a binary SVM, but when I use all the data (10 Gb aproximmately), the optimization figures show up but nothing happens (over the course of days). The computer has enough memory (it shows a 25% usage) and CPU (it shows a 20% usage), so it is not a problem of running out of resources. I believe it may have entered some sort of internal loop, because when I only use 1% of the information, it works fine. Is there some step I'm missing? thanks for your time.

```
cvp = cvpartition(response, 'Holdout', 0.2);
trainingPredictors = predictors(cvp.training, :);
trainingResponse = response(cvp.training, :);
validationPredictors = predictors(cvp.test, :);
validationResponse = response(cvp.test, :);
% Train model
rng default
MdlT= fitcsvm(trainingPredictors, ...
    trainingResponse, ...
    'KernelFunction','rbf',...
    'OptimizeHyperparameters','auto',...
    'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions',...
    struct('AcquisitionFunctionName','expected-improvement-plus'))
```

Comment: What is the difference between “memory” and “RAM”? They’re the same in my book. In any case, it looks like your machine is thrashing (swapping out data from RAM to file to make more space). It looks to me that you do not have enough RAM for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant CPU and memory usage, and both are near 20% capacity (it is a high computing computer)

Comment: SVN is performing a nonlinear optimization. It can only run on a single core. I guess that you have a quad-corde processor and that Matlab simply cannot run faster

Comment: It is reasonable that nothing happens. You might have not yet computed a single matrix inversion. The calculation time grows exponentially. (That you turned on *hyperparameter optimization* won't make you happy. Try to find the optimal parameters on a smaller subset). It also might be better (i.e. faster) using Python in this special case -- for some reason I found it to run faster with SVM